# Missing column error in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I got missing column error in Hibernate. Whole error is like this, org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: enquiry_type_enquiry_type_id in vaccum.enquiry. Here is my code.

```
package com.beans;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.management.loading.PrivateClassLoader;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;


@Entity
@Table(name="enquiry")
public class Enquiry {


    @Id@GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="enquiry_id")
    int enquiry_id;

    @Column(name="text")
    String text;

    @Column(name="location")
    String location;

    @Column(name="name")
    String name;

    @Column(name="mobile")
    String mobile;


    @Column(name="date_time")
    Timestamp date_time;


    /////////////////////


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Enquiry_Type enquiry_type;

    public Enquiry_Type getEnquiry_type() {
        return enquiry_type;
    }

    public void setEnquiry_type(Enquiry_Type enquiry_type) {
        this.enquiry_type = enquiry_type;
    }


    //////////////////////////
    public Enquiry() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Enquiry(String text,String location,String name,String mobile,Timestamp date_time) {

        this.text    = text;
        this.location = location;
        this.name = name;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.date_time = date_time;
    }

    public int getEnquiry_id() {
        return enquiry_id;
    }

    public void setEnquiry_id(int enquiry_id) {
        this.enquiry_id = enquiry_id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public Timestamp getDate_time() {
        return date_time;
    }

    public void setDate_time(Timestamp date_time) {
        this.date_time = date_time;
    }

}
```

Enquiry_Type.java is here,

```
package com.beans;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="enquiry_type")
public class Enquiry_Type {

    @Id@GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="enquiry_type_id")
    int enquiry_id;

    @Column(name="enquiry_type")
    String enquiry_type;

    public Enquiry_Type() {

    }

    public Enquiry_Type(String enquiry_type) {

        this.enquiry_type    = enquiry_type;

    }

    public String getEnquiry_type() {
        return enquiry_type;
    }

    public void setEnquiry_type(String enquiry_type) {
        this.enquiry_type = enquiry_type;
    }



}
```

I getting error from `SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();`. That code is given below,

```
//creating configuration object
Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file

//creating seession factory object
SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
//creating session object
Session session=factory.openSession();

//creating transaction object
Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
```

Table-1: Enquiry

---

### enquiry_id | text | location | name | mobile | type | date_time  |

Table-2: Enquiry_Type

---

### enquiry_type_id | enquiry_type |

here, Enquiry.type = Enquiry_Type.enquiry_type_id

Comment: hey you have missed out @column name annotation for the enquiry_type feild. it might be because of that

Comment: Yes, because it is foreign key constraints. So, I have tried to write this field on `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` annotation, but it shows that on this relationship you couldn't apply this. @war_Hero

Comment: yes thats proper but, if you do not write @column name annotation then that feild is never created in the database

Answer (score 1):

How do you generate database schema? If you are using hibernate to do it, you should change value of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property to "create" or "create-drop".

Comment: I have used "validate". @over9k

Comment: By using "create" or "create-drop" it crate the whole table new every time. So, it's not that solution what i want. Because, i want previous data in database. And yes it change field name "type" to "enquiry_type_enquiry_type_id" in table-1, which have foreign key. @over9k

Answer (score 0):

Can you Cross check whether you have got a column called "enquiry_type_enquiry_type_id " in the table "enquiry".

You have to make sure all the columns present in the table should be present in the entity Class

Comment: Can you add your table structure also to the question

Comment: Well that is the catch :) .You have annotated the table as "@Table(name="enquiry_type") "   .So your class should have the columns present in Enquiry_Type table. ie ,Enquiry_Type and enquiry_type_id should be present in your Enquiry_Type class.Try it out

Comment: I have upadate my answer, and shown another class which have Enquiry_Type and enquiry_type_id. @Thomas

Comment: No. Many things i have applied but not solved. @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your requirement, if you want to insert Parent element together with its new OneToMany children by cascade property,use below one.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Enquiry_Type enquiry_type;
```

The annotation @JoinColumn indicates that this entity is the owner of the relationship i.e. the corresponding table has a column with a foreign key to the referenced table)

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "enquiryTypeID")
private Enquiry_Type enquiry_type;
```